# Jenkins updating init.groovy.d files in a docker container

Tags: docker, jenkins, groovy

I have a series of Groovy scripts in groovy.init.d inside a Docker container which has the JENKINS_HOME mounted to the host file system.

I'm using the standard jenkins-support file to copy the plugins et al.
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jenkinsci/docker/master/jenkins-support

When I add new files to groovy.init.d, the script adds them no problem, but if I update the scripts then the newer ones are not overwriting the existing ones. I want the groovy files added to the Docker image to overwrite what is on the file system.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 12):

Yes, put  .override extension to your file and put to /usr/share/jenkins/ref/init.groovy.d/ on the 
**image example**

`/usr/share/jenkins/ref/init.groovy.d/security.groovy.override`  .

When jenkins starts it will replace existing

`/var/jenkins_home/init.groovy.d/security.groovy`

file's content with the one above.

Comment: Thank you, this is actually very helpful, was struggling to understanding how the cache was being invalidated when rebuilding jenkins image, but the changes were not being reflected inside the container and kept using old .groovy scripts. Fail to understand why OP never accepted this answer, but I guess that's what happen in SO